# CSS not Working on iphone 4

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive site sandbox.mercomcorp.com I am currently working on the iphone 4 in landscape.  I am trying to get the telephone numbers at the top to come down where the social icons are here is my css. I am not understanding why when I put top into the css its not working can someone help me? Below is my css for that block

```
#block-66
{
    font-weight:bold;
  /*  background:blue;*/
    position:absolute!important;
    left:-215px!important;
    top:245px!important;

}
```

Comment: Im sorry but your CSS is a mess. You should not have !important after every single rule. The top rule is working it is just set to -45px in your media query @media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px)

Comment: @GifCo thanks but that did not work. Whats wrong with my css besides the comments?

Comment: I see you have changed it to Top: 45px now instead of -45px. I am only emulating an iPhone in Chrome dev tools so cant say for sure it will work but if you change that to top: 200px it gets it pretty close to where you want it. Ill post an answer with a screen shot below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, your rule is the third in the list, and the 'top' position if overridden by two other rules, in two different media-queries.

(I wanted to post a screenshot of the console, but I can't)

In your case, you have to define your rules after the main rules that is applied.

The

```
media="all"
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px)
#block-66 {...}
```

rule is somewhere in the code, and taking precedence over your rule. Try to find it and append your rule after this one.

Also, you should avoid using !important, when possible, and make use of a correct ordering instead.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Please see screen shot of media query and rule I am altering to move the phone numbers.

[image]